# syntax error con condicional if

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Por alguna razón me da un error de sintaxis cuando incluyo un if en mi código. Me hace referencia a una linea que no tiene ningún error. Esto pasa incluso cuando solo pongo la estructura del if en la vista.

El error solo desaparece cuando borro la estructura completa del if. Sin importar que deje las sentencias  que contiene

Este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi vista:

```
            <section class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">

                      {{-- columna izquierda --}}
                        <div class="col-md-5"> 
                          <div class="card card-success">
                            <div class="card-header">
                              <h3 class="card-title">Imagen de la factura</h3>
                            </div>
                            {{-- Se abre la imagen --}}
                            <img src="{{ Storage::url($imagen->imagen)}}" height="900px"> 
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        {{-- Columna derecha --}}

                          <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="card card-success">
                              <div class="card-header">
                                  <h3 class="card-title">Formulario de registro</h3>
                              </div>
                              @include('partials.validation-errors')
                              <section class="content">

                                @if ({{$imagen->tipo_factura}} == '606')

                                <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{  route('facturas.store') }}">
                                  @include('facturas._form',['ruta'=> $imagen, 'btnText' => 'Guardar'])

                                @else
                                    Es un 607
                                @endif

                              </section>
                            </div><!-- /.card -->
                          </div>

                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            <div>
          </section><!-- /.content -->

    @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis debe ser :

```
@if ($imagen->tipo_factura == '606')
    //...
```

Pudes leerlo en la documentación de Laravel Blade

[Sentencias if](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements)

> Puedes construir sentencias `if` utilizando las directivas `@if`, `@elseif`, `@else` y `@endif`.  Estas directivas funcionan de manera idéntica a sus contrapartes PHP.

Comment: Gracias, no me habia fijado en eso.